# Python reshaping based on column names keeping ID & other rows

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to reshape a df so it stacks columns based on a similarity in column name while keeping the unique ID portion of the column name in a new column?

I have a df similar to the following (my actual data also includes NaN values that need to remain):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"RX_9mm": scipy.randn(5), "RY_9mm": scipy.randn(5),"TX_9mm": scipy.randn(5), "TY_9mm": scipy.randn(5), "RX_10mm": scipy.randn(5), "RY_10mm": scipy.randn(5),"TX_10mm": scipy.randn(5), "TY_10mm": scipy.randn(5), "time": range(5)})

    RX_9mm  RY_9mm  TX_9mm  TY_9mm  RX_10mm  RY_10mm  TX_10mm  TY_10mm  time
0 -0.1444  2.1319  1.9665  0.1773   0.5156  -1.8461   0.9122   1.1285     0
1  1.4831 -0.8773 -1.0112 -0.0010   1.4532  -1.3721   0.6894  -0.1781     1
2  0.3685  0.2148 -1.2216  0.0098  -1.1427  -0.1851   0.3890   0.9552     2
3  0.6843 -2.0279 -1.1342 -0.8869   0.2718  -2.4857  -1.0496  -0.4286     3
4 -1.5625 -0.2733 -0.1243 -1.2248  -0.7403  -0.5840   0.1797  -0.7014     4
```

However I need it to look like this:

```
       RX      RY      TX      TY time   ID
0 -0.1444  2.1319  1.9665  0.1773    0  9mm
1  1.4831 -0.8773 -1.0112 -0.0010    1  9mm
2  0.3685  0.2148 -1.2216  0.0098    2  9mm
3  0.6843 -2.0279 -1.1342 -0.8869    3  9mm
4 -1.5625 -0.2733 -0.1243 -1.2248    4  9mm
5  0.5156 -1.8461  0.9122  1.1285    0 10mm  
6  1.4532 -1.3721  0.6894 -0.1781    1 10mm
7 -1.1427 -0.1851  0.3890  0.9552    2 10mm
8  0.2718 -2.4857 -1.0496 -0.4286    3 10mm
9 -0.7403 -0.5840  0.1797 -0.7014    4 10mm
```

I tried to use the following code from an example from 'Reshaping dataframes in pandas based on column labels' by Chang She

However when I use the following code:

```
id = df.ix[:, ['time']]
df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df.columns])
pandas.merge(df.stack(0).reset_index(1), id, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I get:

```
       RX      RY      TX      TY      RX      RY      TX      TY time
      9mm     9mm     9mm     9mm    10mm    10mm    10mm    10mm  NaN
0 -0.1444  2.1319  1.9665  0.1773  0.5156 -1.8461  0.9122  1.1285    0
1  1.4831 -0.8773 -1.0112 -0.0010  1.4532 -1.3721  0.6894 -0.1781    1
2  0.3685  0.2148 -1.2216  0.0098 -1.1427 -0.1851  0.3890  0.9552    2
3  0.6843 -2.0279 -1.1342 -0.8869  0.2718 -2.4857 -1.0496 -0.4286    3
4 -1.5625 -0.2733 -0.1243 -1.2248 -0.7403 -0.5840  0.1797 -0.7014    4
```

I understand that the new columns are multi level with the measurement (RX, RY etc.) and the ID (9mm, 10mm) levels, but I don't understand how to stack the measurements into the same columns while keeping the ID as a new column.

If anyone could explain what I am doing wrong to get this output and not the stacked columns, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your solution, last `merge` is not necessary, because is converted column `time` to `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in first step:

```
df = df.set_index('time')
#expand=True in columns create MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
#rename_axis set MultiIndex names for names of columns after reset index
df = df.stack(dropna=False).rename_axis(['time','ID']).reset_index()
print (df)
   time    ID        RX        RY        TX        TY
0     0  10mm -0.549487 -0.349412 -0.620500  0.992223
1     0   9mm  0.831292 -2.465550 -0.863001 -1.335898
2     1  10mm  0.214057 -0.136649  1.831669 -0.672306
3     1   9mm -0.372416 -1.633798 -0.414518 -1.426492
4     2  10mm  0.480018  1.575599 -1.330841 -0.780036
5     2   9mm  0.352044 -1.008269  1.339841  0.423539
6     3  10mm -0.822354  0.002455 -1.099829  0.060929
7     3   9mm  1.336161 -0.066224 -1.111453  1.651180
8     4  10mm  0.627119 -0.419848  1.052179 -0.426928
9     4   9mm  0.701500 -0.833526  2.563398  0.749432
```

If want change ordering of columns is possible use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df = df[np.r_[df.columns[2:], df.columns[:2]]]
print (df)
         RX        RY        TX        TY  time    ID
0 -0.549487 -0.349412 -0.620500  0.992223     0  10mm
1  0.831292 -2.465550 -0.863001 -1.335898     0   9mm
2  0.214057 -0.136649  1.831669 -0.672306     1  10mm
3 -0.372416 -1.633798 -0.414518 -1.426492     1   9mm
4  0.480018  1.575599 -1.330841 -0.780036     2  10mm
5  0.352044 -1.008269  1.339841  0.423539     2   9mm
6 -0.822354  0.002455 -1.099829  0.060929     3  10mm
7  1.336161 -0.066224 -1.111453  1.651180     3   9mm
8  0.627119 -0.419848  1.052179 -0.426928     4  10mm
9  0.701500 -0.833526  2.563398  0.749432     4   9mm
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works like a charm.

Comment: Will do, but one further question: I just tried it with my data which has value rows (i.e. RX, RY, TX, TZ) that have NaN values. The stacking removes them in the process. Is there a way to keep the NaN rows?

Comment: @VacciniumC - Sure, use `df.stack(dropna=False)` in [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)